# Problem while using state from React-Redux ___ Property 'cart' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState' - from a MERN project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, mern

the error i am getting as per VS Code is ---
Property 'productDetails' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'

to more elaborate the problem as follows,
I have tried the solutions given on the page, however none worked for me. so my problem is as follows:

```
//While I am using 

const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList)  

//I am getting that property does not exist. the codes can be seen from the below images
```

[this is the store.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y9TIL.png)

[And this is the file where I am trying to use > const productList = useSelector((state) => state.productList](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnJYx.png)

the error can be clearly seen in the second image Property 'cart' does not exist on type 'DefaultRootState'.ts(2339)

this is a MERN Project.

Comment: This is actually a typescript problem. There’s little you can without using typescript, one way or another.

Comment: is there any major issue if I ignore the warning ?

Comment: No, there's no major consequence.